# Passing scanner to a method

Tags: java

Just a basic newbie question I can't see to find a good answer to online.

I'm writing code for a course and I am finding myself passing scanner to quite a few methods.

First question is generally speaking is this frowned upon? Presses a key will it disrupt during runtime?

```
        // Countinously prompt the user for a file.
    Scanner input = null;        
    while ( input == null ){
        System.out.println ( "What is the name of the file containing each student's responses to the 10 questions? " );
        try {
            input = new Scanner ( new File ( in.nextLine ( ) ));
        } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
              System.out.println ( "You must input a valid file name." );
        }
    }

    //Print and store student answers
    ArrayList <String> answers = new ArrayList <String> ();
    studentResponses ( input, answers );

    //Analyze the answers
    ansAnalysis( input );
```

as you can see I pass scanner to a few methods, as a beginner just not use to it and figured I'd have seen more examples if this was a common technique. I suppose I could create another object, but this seems easier.

Comment: Passing the scanner around is completely reasonable. You have methods that continue to read input from the same file, and so your code matches your intent. This is some of the saner looking "newbie" code I've seen on SO in a while. I'd say you're fine.

Comment: And no, pressing a key won't disrupt `input`, as `input` is reading from the file.

Comment: thanks so much I appreciate the quick answer, with so much info online I felt guilty asking. glad i did.

Answer (score 0):

If these are all just methods in a single class you might as well just declare the scanner to be an instance variable (declare it outside of all methods).

Comment: I think that would be a bit of a regression. Getting in the habit of doing it the way the OP is doing it is great, especially for future more complicated projects. E.g. perhaps, in the future, a list of files will have to be processed; it is trivial to add that feature if `studentResponses()` and `ansAnalysis()` take the input source directly.